# Image view во весь экран?

Tags: android

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать следующую задачу.
Есть Imageview с изображением подгружаемым от сервера. Как реализовать так что бы при нажатии на imageview он открывался во весь экран! Пример как в галлереи? Нажимаешь на картинку и она открывается во весь экран?

Как я думаю что можно это решить. Создать Активити с одним image view с параметрами width и height fill_parent. После того как я кликаю на imageview маленького изображения, открывается новое activity и показывается изображение! Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно, обычно полноэкранный просмотр изображения - это отдельная активность.

Есть очень много готовых библиотек.

- [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)
- [Subsampling-scale-image-view](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)
- [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)
- [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)
- [ByakuGallery](https://github.com/diegocarloslima/ByakuGallery)
- [AndroidTouchGallery](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery)

Смотреть лучше по примерам.

Comment: Восопльзовался PhotoView правда в grandel работает старая версия     compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'

Comment: Благодрю за совет - первая библиотека, простая и понятная в использовании